# Pass object as parameter for constructor among with saving the context

Tags: javascript

TL;DR:

1. I want to pass object as a parameter when creating a new instance of a class (`ChildClass`)
2. When I'm passing the parameters I want to save the context so `.this` should refer to the object where this instance was creating (not the context of the reference)

**parent.class.js**

```
class ParentClass {
    constructor(nativeObject, param1, param2) {
        this.nativeObject = nativeObject;
        this.param1 = param1;
        this.param2 = param2;
    }
    // some logic here
}
module.exports = { ParentClass };
```

**child.class.js**

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    // some logic here
}
module.exports = { ChildClass };
```

**usingclasses.js**

```
let { ChildClass } = require('path/to/my/child/class');

let param1 = 'idkSomeString';
let param2 = 42;

class MyCoolClass {
    createChild() {
        return new ChildClass(this, param1, param2);
    }
}
module.exports = { MyCoolClass };
```

As you can see I'm passing here `this` bc in ParenClass I need to know (that logic is not included in the example) where that instance of the ChildClass was created.
There are many files like **usingclasses.js** with different classes but each has it's own createChild() method which creates the ChildClass.

What I want to achieve

**usingclasses.js**

```
let { ChildClass } = require('path/to/my/child/class');

let paramsObj1 = {
    nativeObject: ' ', // ?????,
    param1: 'idkSomeString',
    param2: 42
};

let paramsObj2 = {
    nativeObject: ' ', // ?????,
    param1: 'idkSomeString',
    param2: 42
};
class MyCoolClass {
    createChild() {
        return new ChildClass(paramsObj1 );
    }

    createAnotherChild() {
        return new ChildClass(paramsObj2);
    }
}
```

So first question is:
How can I store all the `params` in a separate variable (object) at the top
so I can simply do

`new ChildClass(objectWithParams1)` ,

`new ChildClass(objectWithParams2)`

...

`new ChildClass(objectWithParamsN)`

And how can I pass the context (first argument in ParentClass constructor) so it will refer to the object where the instance of this class was created?

I do realize that if I will do

```
let params = {
    nativeObject: this,
    param1: 'idkSomeString',
    param2: 42
};
```

`this` will refer to the `params` object but I need the constructor to know that it was created in the `MyCoolClass`

**UPDATE**
After researching I'm curious does `.bind` has something do to with this kind of issues. When I actually need to specify what `this` is referring to?

Can I somehow specify that `this` is referring to MyCoolClass?

This will allow me to store everything at the top and then just pass the one single object as parameter when creating new instance of the ChildClass

Comment: *"I do realize that if I will do ... `this` will refer to the `params` object"* No, it won't. It'll refer to whatever `this` is where that object literal is.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you are right. Maybe I should wrote "I tried it and that did not set the nativeObject to MyCoolClass". I guess it's because the prams variable is declared before MyCoolClass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way to do it is the way you showed in your first example (but keep reading for an alternative): By passing `this` into `ChildClass` as an argument:

```
class MyCoolClass {
    createChild() {
        return new ChildClass(this, paramsObj1);
    }

    createAnotherChild() {
        return new ChildClass(this, paramsObj2);
    }
}
```

`ChildClass`'s constructor would look like:

```
constructor(parentObject, params) {
    super(parentObject, params.param1, params.param2);
}
```

or

```
constructor(parentObject, {param1, param2}) {
    super(parentObject, param1, param2);
}
```

But if you really want to pass just one thing into `ChildClass`, you'll have to assign it from within `MyCoolClass`'s code, perhaps like this:

```
class MyCoolClass {
    createChild() {
        return new ChildClass({parentObject: this, ...paramsObj1});
    }

    createAnotherChild() {
        return new ChildClass({parentObject: this, ...paramsObj2});
    }
}
```

`ChildClass`'s constructor would look like:

```
constructor(params) {
    super(params.parentObject, params.param1, params.param2);
}
```

or

```
constructor({parentObject, param1, param2}) {
    super(parentObject, param1, param2);
}
```

Comment: That's a great idea to start with. I just need one clarification: Do I really have to include constructor in ChildClass (because it actually does not have one it just inherits the parent one)? Can I just change the very first constructor (in ParentClass) to retrieve object the way you showed?

Comment: @anotheruser - Yes, that's absolutely fine. If you don't have a constructor in `ChildClass`, the JavaScript engine will create one for you that looks like this: `constructor(...args) { super(...args); }`. So if `ParentClass` expects what `MyCoolClass` passes to `ChildClass`, you're good. :-)

Comment: I'm marking you answer as correct. It helped me a lot. If you are looking forward helping newbies please check my next question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59387568/a-way-to-retrieve-the-context-without-passing-this-as-parameter